# How to make a textbox display a different field than it controls?

Tags: ms-access

So at the top of my page I have a combo box to select the current employee. The form is chiefly made up of checklist items to be completed. I set up a macro, so that when a checkbox next to the item is clicked, it will populate the 'CompletedBy' field with whatever value was in the combo box at the top of the page. That way they can select their name once, and then check off any items they have completed, and their respective name will be recorded for each item they have done.

HOWEVER I want it to DISPLAY the employees name, but actually manipulate the 'EmployeeID' field.

So how do I make a textbox display a value, but manipulate a different value in a table>? Or if this is impossible, what other paradigm could I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tutorial on how to [bind combo box to primary key but display a description field](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/comboboxes/bind_index.php): this works on old version of `Microsoft Access`. I don't know if newer versions of `Microsoft Access` use a different and simpler approach (i.e.: `.DisplayMember` and `.ValueMember` properties of a `ComboBox` in `VB.NET`).